# How to load image to the image control in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to load image to the image control which i dragged  from the tools. Named as 'Logo'
The file path i have given is from my D:\Photos\ .

I have written code as follows

```
 Logo.ImageUrl ="D:\Photos\image1.jpeg" ;
```

Image control code is as follows

```
    <asp:Image ID="Logo" runat="server" Height="99px" 
         Width="119px" />
```

The image is present in the given location but it is not loading. It is not giving any error.

Can any one tell What changes i have to make to load the image in run time.?

Comment: delete the image tag and recreate new image tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your path incorrect, try to use  `Server.MapPath()` after storing images in project it self

Please read this documentation about [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Comment: A relative path that is resolved against the current page path.
Logo.ImageUrl ="Images/SampleImage.jpg"; part helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You can not access `physical paths` (like `Drives`) of a `client machine` from web application due to `security` issues.

**Solution :**
1.create `Photos` folder in your current project folder.
2.copy all required images into `Photos` folder .
3.try to access the images from `Photos` folder path.
4.Provide `tilde` `~` operator to specify the `current project` folder.
5.Use `Server.MapPath()` function to convert the given `relative path` into the `absolute path`.

Try This :

```
Logo.ImageUrl =Server.MapPath("~/Photos/image1.jpeg");
```

Comment: yes inside  my project folder i created photos folder. how to give path to load image if i give path like ~/Photos/image1.jpeg that is giving error.

Comment: @Raghuveera: use `Server.MapPath` see my edited answer.

Comment: it is pointing to C:\Program Files\Common Files inside some folder.

Comment: Logo.ImageUrl =Server.MapPath("~/Photos/image1.jpeg"); also not working.

Comment: @Raghuveera user firebug and then check what the path image is taking, and try to modify the path of image in firebug itself to check exact problem

Comment: try some thing like this Server.MapPath("Photos/image1.jpeg"); check without ~

Comment: @Raghuveera: chck wether your image file extension is `jpg` or `jpeg`

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi i checked with both. it is giving error like this 'file:/D:/VPhotos/image1.jpeg' is not a valid virtual path.'

Comment: @Raghuveera: try -> `Logo.ImageUrl ="~/Photos/image1.jpeg";`

Answer (score 0):

Either try what @Sudhakar Tillapudi said or
do something like file://D://Photos//image1.jpeg

You have web application that can be installed on web server anywhere in the world and on any given system so you hav 2 options:
- set image url as URL :)

EXAMPLE:

> http://somewherefarfarawy.com/image.jpg

- set image url as path to local resource 
  file://D://temp//logo.jpg is in opera traslated as file://localhost/D://temp//logo.jpg

Comment: if i try that path it is giving the error like this ''file:/D:/VPhotos/image1.jpeg' is not a valid virtual path.'

Comment: try it in browser first

Answer (score 0):

Use handler for display images

to create handler follow this link
http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Add handler to image

```
<asp:Image runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx %>'>
```

in the handler pass the image ass byte stream

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{


  //get the image from data base in here im using a web service
    System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    MMS_MasterWebService.MMS_MasterMaintenance obj = new MMS_MasterWebService.MMS_MasterMaintenance();
    obj.Url =  "http://192.168.48.10/SHOREVision_MMS_Service/MMS_MasterMaintenance.asmx";
    ds = obj.GetVehicleMasterByCode(para);
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][21]);

}
```